# ASNE Invalid or expired token, how can to check if system clock is in sync?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to login to Twitter through my app using ASNE. Unfortunately, I get the following error. I know my credentials are correct, I did give all the necessary permissions, and I also put in a callback url. I also tried regenerating the keys. Im assuming it must be the system clock, how can I check for this error?

[image]

```
mSocialNetworkManager = (SocialNetworkManager) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG);
        if (mSocialNetworkManager == null) {
            mSocialNetworkManager = new SocialNetworkManager();
            TwitterSocialNetwork twNetwork = new TwitterSocialNetwork(this, TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            mSocialNetworkManager.addSocialNetwork(twNetwork);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mSocialNetworkManager, SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG).commit();
            mSocialNetworkManager.setOnInitializationCompleteListener(this);
        } else {
            //if manager exist - get and setup login only for initialized SocialNetworks
            if(!mSocialNetworkManager.getInitializedSocialNetworks().isEmpty()) {
                List<SocialNetwork> socialNetworks = mSocialNetworkManager.getInitializedSocialNetworks();
                for (SocialNetwork socialNetwork : socialNetworks) {
                    socialNetwork.setOnLoginCompleteListener(this);
                }
            }
        }
        SocialNetwork socialNetwork = mSocialNetworkManager.getSocialNetwork(TWITTER);
        if(!socialNetwork.isConnected() && TWITTER != 0) {
            socialNetwork.requestLogin();
        } else {
            socialNetwork.requestPostMessage("success!");
        }
```